# Is Blend-Exchange still active and operational?

Tags: discussion

I installed via Tampermonkey and TM says it has access to the site (Blender Stack Exchange).  However, there is no button above this question's formatting buttons.
[image]

If Blend-Exchange isn't the preferred method of hosting .blends, what is?

Comment: Why don't you go to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and try it manually? Other than that, this might be a topic for meta.

Comment: Blend file hosting provided by Blend Exchange is a third party courtesy of GiantCowFilms, not officially part of Stack Exchange as far as I know. It was recently rewritten from the ground up and completely revamped. The script was probably not updated to the current version, as such it is likely outdated.

Comment: The extension should be working, the [latest version]() ([2.02]

Answer (score 2):

The extension should be working, the [latest version](https://github.com/gandalf3/BlendExchanger) (2.02) appears properly for me. Note that it currently doesn't support unposted questions, as blend-exchange requires the question URL and the extension can't know that until after the question has been posted. So unfortunately for now you'll just have to post your question and then edit to upload a .blend.